# FMX Style lost on old version of Windows

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm having a doubt about styling applications in FMX.

I developed an application using Delphi 11 on Windows 10, but when I open the app on an older version of Windows, some components lose their style, for example `TButton`, `TEdit`, `TProgressBar`, etc.

Can we fix that? Or, is this a compatibility issue?

ob:occurs in modified components in Style Designer

Windows 7 and 8.1

[image]

Windows 10

[image]

Any tips or ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: You say: *...some components lose the style.* Please be specific. IF you talk about the different font for the text "Log in", it is possible that the other computer doesn't have the chosen font, and substitutes it in order to still show the text. If you talk about the different color of the form (white vs. almost white), perhaps the computers are setup with different color schemes? Only you can check that. If you talk about the button color beeing blue vs light-gray, it could be because of enabled vs disabled, as the one that is blue, could be enabled because info is entered in one text box.

Comment: All my speculations above may be wrong, so please edit your question to be specific about the differences you claim to be because of the styling. But keep in mind that all programs rely to some degree on services that the OS provides, and that OS's appearance change with versions, and even in same versions, but depending on user preferred setup.

Comment: Okay, I don't think I specified what's really lost in style. Some components such as TButton, TProgressbar, Tedits, and among others, when I modify or create the style of some visual components in Delphi's Style Designer, in Windows 10 loads the style correctly but in older versions this problem occurs and as if i did not load the modified style.

Comment: Check the [ControlType](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Controls.Presentation.TPresentedControl.ControlType) property of the components that lose styled look on older Windows versions and make sure it is set to `Styled` and not `Platform`. If it is set to `Platform` then the components use native look of the specific platform that your application is being ran on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FMX can apply [distinct styles](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles#Style_Resource_Storage:_Multi-Platform_TStyleBook) to each of your target platforms so it's up to you to ensure that your style is available across all of them (major Windows versions are considered distinct *platforms* as well).

You can check your supported platforms by opening your `TStyleBook` and looking into the "Platform" selector. Chances are you only have `Windows 10 Desktop` and `Default` listed. To apply the styles you already have to `Windows 7`, `Windows 8.1` and other platforms:

- Add platforms by clicking the "Add new platform" button (just right from the selector), choose your target platform and finally copy/paste your styles from `Windows 10 Desktop`.
- Move all your styles from the `Windows 10 Desktop` platform to the `Default` platform. When no specific style for a platform is defined the `Default` one is applied.